# Remove /category/ from category (archive) page URLs (without using a plugin)

Tags: php, categories, permalinks, urls

A Category page URL structure looks like this:

`example.com/category/cat/child_cat/`

How can we do:

`example.com/cat/child_cat/`

Without the use of a plugin (eg, [Yoast](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/))?

Comment: The two permalink examples you provided are the same. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: You don't need a plugin, or any code whatsoever ;)

Comment: Ha sorry, edited!

Comment: @AlexanderHolsgrove cheeky!

Comment: May this blog will helpful for you - https://muffingroup.com/blog/remove-category-from-wordpress-url/

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in functions.php to remove the "category" text from permalink.

```
function remove_category( $string, $type ) {
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) ){
        $url_without_category = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
        return trailingslashit( $url_without_category );
    }
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'remove_category', 100, 2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Following these two simple steps, you can successfully remove “/category/” from your WordPress website’s URLs. This not only makes your links look cleaner but also enhances the user experience.

In the Permalinks page, find the “Category base” field. By default, it’s set to “/category/.” replace with (.)

now edit theme function.php file, add this code

```
function remove_remane_category( $string, $type )  { if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )   { $url_without_category = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );  return trailingslashit( $url_without_category ); }  return $string; }     add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'remove_remane_category', 100, 2);
```